# python dictionary iteration for data frame filtering with multiple conditions

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary

I am basically trying to build basic search engine that returns results based on a parsed query.

I have a dictionary that is user generated based on parsed input from their string:

```
input = {“color”: [“black”], “make”: [“honda”], “type”: [“”]}
```

I am then trying to use that input, to do a search and filter of a dataset (which I am currently storing as a pandas dataframe, so please advise if this is also not optimal).

```
list(df.column.values) = make,type,color,mpg,year

honda,coupe,red,32,2014
bmw,suv,black,21,2012
honda,suv,black,24,2015
vw,sedan,black,31,2016
```

I need to iterate over the valid values of my input dictionary (notice that ‘type’ doesn’t have a value) and filter based on what the user entered in, ‘color’ and ‘make’). Sometimes they might include the type and leave out the color, etc. so I might never have a value for every key in my dictionary;

Sudo code:

```
for each valid value in my input dictionary:
    filter df by appropriate_column=appropriate_value
```

So given my input example, I would filter my df down to only entries that were ‘black’ and made by ‘honda’.

Comment: Please provide example data we can use in the code, i.e. a small data frame with a few rows.
Also, what have you tried so far? Querying in pandas is pretty basic, at least for values of a single column. Do you know how to do that already?

Comment: Yes, I do know already how to filter in pandas for a specified column / multiple columns, however implementing it dynamically each time for conditions that might vary, i am not sure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let `d` be your dict, then:

```
cond = [df[k].apply(lambda k: k in v if v != [''] else True) for k, v in d.items()]
cond_total = functools.reduce(lambda x, y: x & y, cond)
print(df[cond_total])
```

Output:

```
    make type  color  mpg  year
2  honda  suv  black   24  2015
```